# PHP - Add String to Array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, string, variables

I am wondering how I can add a string variable to the current array. For example, I have an array called `$finalarray`. Then I have a loop that adds a value on every run. Basically:

```
$finalarray = $results_array + string;
```

A very basic structure. I am using this for MySQL so that I can retrieve the final array of the column.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table";
$showresult = mysql_query($query);

while($results_array = mysql_fetch_assoc($showresult))
{
  $finalarray =  $finalarray + $results_array["column"];
}
```

Edit:

Currently using this code (still not working):

```
    $query = “SELECT * FROM table”;
$showresult = mysql_query($query);

while($results_array = mysql_fetch_assoc($showresult))
{
  $finalarray[] = $results_array["name"];
}

echo $finalarray;
```

The problem is that it just says "Array"

Thanks,

Kevin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer to your `edited` question:

You cannot use just a single `echo` to print the entire array contents. Instead

Use

```
var_dump($finalarray);
```

or

```
print_r($finalarray);
```

to print the array contents..

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`[]`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.modifying) notation. [`+`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php) is for unioning two arrays.

```
$array = array('foo');

$array[] = 'bar'.

// $array == array('foo', 'bar')
```

Comment: If I add the two brackets, my array is a list of strings that say "Array" over and over again.

Comment: @Kevin Could you show us the actual code with which this is happening?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the function `array_push` or `[]` notation:

```
array_push($array, 'hi');

$array[] = 'hi';
```

Comment: what is this code actually doing? I don't get why you "push" 'hi' to array, but then you assign hi to the end of the array. Aren't you essentially adding it twice, then?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table";
$showresult = mysql_query($query);

while($results_array = mysql_fetch_assoc($showresult))
{
    $finalarray[] = $results_array["column"];
}

// Add X to the end of the array
$finalarray[] = "X";
```

Answer (score 0):

Codaddict is correct.  You are looking to output the last element that was added to the array.

```
echo end($final_array);
```

That will move the array's pointer to the last element added to it and then output it.  Since you're adding the elements to the array in this manner...

```
$finalarray[] = $results_array["name"];
```

The key for each of your elements will be sequential, 0,1,2,3...so on and so forth.  Another less elegant solution to get the last element would be...

```
echo $final_array[count($final_array) - 1];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo implode($finalarray);
```

Or with a custom join "glue"

```
echo implode(', ', $finalarray);
```